# How to use pretrained encoder for customized Unet

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, pytorch, pretraining

if you have a standard Unet encoder such as resnet50, then it's easy to add pertaining to it. for example:

```
ENCODER = 'resnet50'
ENCODER_WEIGHTS = 'imagenet'
CLASSES = class_names
ACTIVATION = 'sigmoid' # could be None for logits or 'softmax2d' for multiclass segmentation

# create segmentation model with pretrained encoder
model = smp.Unet(
    encoder_name=ENCODER, 
    encoder_weights=ENCODER_WEIGHTS, 
    classes=len(CLASSES), 
    activation=ACTIVATION,
)

preprocessing_fn = smp.encoders.get_preprocessing_fn(ENCODER, ENCODER_WEIGHTS)
```

However, suppose you have a custom-made Unet (not necessarily use resent50) encoder such as:

```
class VGGBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, middle_channels, out_channels):
        super().__init__()
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, middle_channels, 3, padding=1)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(middle_channels)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(middle_channels, out_channels, 3, padding=1)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.conv1(x)
        out = self.bn1(out)
        out = self.relu(out)

        out = self.conv2(out)
        out = self.bn2(out)
        out = self.relu(out)

        return out


class UNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes, input_channels=3, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        nb_filter = [32, 64, 128, 256, 512]

        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.up = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear', align_corners=True)

        self.conv0_0 = VGGBlock(input_channels, nb_filter[0], nb_filter[0])
        self.conv1_0 = VGGBlock(nb_filter[0], nb_filter[1], nb_filter[1])
        self.conv2_0 = VGGBlock(nb_filter[1], nb_filter[2], nb_filter[2])
        self.conv3_0 = VGGBlock(nb_filter[2], nb_filter[3], nb_filter[3])
        self.conv4_0 = VGGBlock(nb_filter[3], nb_filter[4], nb_filter[4])

        self.conv3_1 = VGGBlock(nb_filter[3]+nb_filter[4], nb_filter[3], nb_filter[3])
        self.conv2_2 = VGGBlock(nb_filter[2]+nb_filter[3], nb_filter[2], nb_filter[2])
        self.conv1_3 = VGGBlock(nb_filter[1]+nb_filter[2], nb_filter[1], nb_filter[1])
        self.conv0_4 = VGGBlock(nb_filter[0]+nb_filter[1], nb_filter[0], nb_filter[0])

        self.final = nn.Conv2d(nb_filter[0], num_classes, kernel_size=1)


    def forward(self, input):
        x0_0 = self.conv0_0(input)
        x1_0 = self.conv1_0(self.pool(x0_0))
        x2_0 = self.conv2_0(self.pool(x1_0))
        x3_0 = self.conv3_0(self.pool(x2_0))
        x4_0 = self.conv4_0(self.pool(x3_0))

        x3_1 = self.conv3_1(torch.cat([x3_0, self.up(x4_0)], 1))
        x2_2 = self.conv2_2(torch.cat([x2_0, self.up(x3_1)], 1))
        x1_3 = self.conv1_3(torch.cat([x1_0, self.up(x2_2)], 1))
        x0_4 = self.conv0_4(torch.cat([x0_0, self.up(x1_3)], 1))

        output = self.final(x0_4)
        return output
```

How to do Imagenet pretraining for the encoder. I assume doing pretraining for the encoder from scratch will take long time. Is there a way to utilize an existing pre-trained encoder such as the resnet50 for such Unet.

Comment: You should use a pretrained backbone if you want to use pretraining, otherwise if you made it from scratch obviously you will have to train it...

Comment: Do you know of any tutorial on how to train a model on ImageNet from scratch?

Comment: You probably dont want to do that given that this is a huge dataset. If you want to use pretrained unet with resnet50 backbone, take a look here : https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models.pytorch

Comment: Thank you .... the issue I have created a customized encoder, I don't think I could use a ready-made encoder like resnet50, unless, I could somehow copy the relevant layer only.